# oAuth 2.0 Throwing 401 When Requesting Token

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

I am connecting to an oAuth2.0 web API.  Lets pretend it's Twitter I am connecting to.

I have a batch job (C# .Net) which connects with no issues.  I have a web UI, which does reporting on the batch job logs and other things.  One of the things I am trying to build on the web UI, is the ability to try to refeed data that originally failed to send in the batch job.

The web UI calls my web API (C# .NET), which then attempts to request a token from Twitter, and then feed the data over using the oAuth2.0 Token.

For some reason when my web API requests a token from Twitter, I get a 401 error.  I do not get an error when my batch job requests a token though.

Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting a 401 when connecting from a web service API?

Once again, I'm not really calling Twitter.  I just thought it would make it easier to understand if I get the oAuth API a name.

Comment: Was web API and batch job compiled at the same time and with the same version of Net?  I want to make sure we are comparing apples with apples and there isn't something different in Net (or windows).

Comment: Yes, same solution, .net version, even call the "Twitter" token API using the same class and method.  the solution has 3 projects, each use the same .net version.  One web project, one batch project, and one utility (API related) project.

Comment: Are all three cases using the same windows account?  Did you try to delete cookies?  five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS (used for authentication) 1.0/1.1 and use TLS 1.2 or newer.  In June Microsoft pushed a security updated which disabled 1.0/1.1 and lots of people recently have had issues.  Client now have to specify TLS 1.2 so the client doesn't default to earlier versions of TLS.  I suspect you are using earlier version of TLS but can't explain why it would happen on only 1 of the 3 apps.  AQre you running on same client?  Maybe a cookie is still enabling 1.0/1.1

Comment: @jdwent I had to add this in my batch job ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.  without it, I get: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: Delete cookies which may cause issues.  When you OR TLS1.2 and SSL3 it doesn't mean code will automatically try both.  You have to make after first request fails, then try again with 2nd.